# A problem in Real Analysis/Topology

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be a non empty part of $\mathbb{R}$, such that $A$ and its complement are two open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

1- Prove that $A$ is not bounded above.

2- Assuming that $A$ complement is non-empty and let $x$ in $A$ complement.
and let $B=${$t\in A$ such that $x\le t$}. Prove that $B$ is non empty and has a lower bound m such that $m\ge x$.

3- Prove that $m\notin A$   and  $m\notin A^{c}$. And conclude that $A=\mathbb{R}$.

4- Let $F$ be non-empty set in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $F$ and $F$ complementary are closed in $R$. What can we say about the set $F$?

**My attempt at the solution:**

For the first question:

I proceeded using a proof by contradiction: So I supposed that $a=Sup(A)$ exists and is in $A$.

So since $A$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then there exists $\varepsilon$>0 such that:

$]a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon[\subset A$ so if we take b=$\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$+a>a which contradicts the fact that a is Sup(A) and therefore Sup(A) isn't in the set A. So it's either in A complement or A is unbounded. We know it can't be in A complement because A complement is also open.

For the second question knowing that B is nonempty and bounded below by $x$ then inf(B) exists in B. So now to prove that m=$inf(B)$.

So by definition of the $inf$ then let's suppose that there exists another m' different from m and is a lower bound of B. We have to prove that m>m'.

By contradiction we'll suppose that m'>m and let $\varepsilon=m'-m>0$

so there exists an t in B such that t< m+$\varepsilon=m'$ . Therefore that's a contradiction with m' being a lower bound of B. So finally m=inf(B)

Is that approach correct for the second problem?

Thank you for you help before hand.

Comment: You can start by saying the emptyness of $B$ implies that $A$ is bounded above contradicting what you allready proved about $A$: is is *not* bounded above.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't argue like that, because the empty set is a subset of every set. You can use part 1, however. Since $x$ is fixed and $A$ is not bounded from above, there will certainly be $t\in A$ which are bigger than $x$.
In other words, if $B$ was empty, then $x$ would be an upper bound for $A$.

Comment: So I can say that since x is fixed and A is not bounded above then there exists at least a $t$ greater than or equal to x such that the set B is nonempty?

Comment: Yes, if $B$ was empty, then $x$ would be an upper bound for $A$.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot conclude from the existence of $a=\sup A$ that $\sup A\in A$. However, either $\sup A\in A$ (and then some $]a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon[\subseteq A$, contradiction because $a$ fails to be an upper bound) or $\sup A\in A^c$ (and then some $]a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon[\subseteq A^c$, contradiction because $a-\epsilon$ is also an upper bound for $A$)

Comment: So if $Sup(A)\in A^{c}$ then there exists an epsilon such that 
$\exists b'>a\in]a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon[\subset A^{c}$ so that's another contradiction because we found another element b' greater than a so a isn't in A complement.